# Sum multiple rows in a joined query

Tags: sql

I'm not even sure how to ask this. So here goes. I have two tables I am joining, and am needing to sum one column of data, easy enough, but the data that needs to be summed is dependent on a certain character associated with the same job number from a different table.

```
Table1
JobNumber       CostType      Amount
1               A              10
1               B              20
1               C              50
1               C              50
3               C              75
```

```
    Table 2
    JobNumber       Status        Value
    1               A             100
    2               I             50
    3               A             75
```

Okay, so some of the jobs will have multiple lines for *CostType* 'C'. I'm trying to display all *JobNumber*s with the total of any amounts for *CostType* C, BUT only for jobs that have the *Status* of 'A'. Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT Table1.JobNumber
      ,Table1.Amount
      ,Table2.Value
  FROM DB.Table1, DB.Table2
  WHERE Table1.JobNumber = Table2.JobNumber and Table1.CostType = 'C' and Table2.Status = 'A'
  GROUP BY Table1.JobNumber, Table1.Amount, Table2.Value
  ORDER BY Table1.JobNumber ASC
```

It's giving me the list of job numbers, their amounts, and the contract value, and only for *CostType* 'C' and with the *Status* of 'A'. But each separate *CostType* 'C' amount has its own row. Is there a way to combine them and display the total *Amount* along with the *Value* for each *JobNumber*, like this?

```
JobNumber     CostTypeCTotal     Value
1             100                100
3             75                 75
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Try aggregating `table1` *before* joining the tables:

```
SELECT t2.JobNumber, t1.c_Amount, t2.Value
FROM DB.Table2 t2
     (SELECT JobNumber,
             SUM(CASE WHEN CostType = 'C' THEN amount END) as c_amount
      FROM DB.Table1 t1
      GROUP BY JobNumber
      HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN CostType = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
     ) t1 JOIN
     ON t1.JobNumber = t2.JobNumber;
```

Note:  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Such use of `,` is archaic syntax that has been out of date since the 1990s.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I don't know where I learned such ancient syntax. As for your answer, I need to ask, where do I need to swap in my actual database names? Is it every instance of t1/t2 etc or just in the from clause?

Comment: @GenericITUnprofessional . . . `t1` and `t2` are table aliases.  The table names you have provided in your query are `db.table2` and `db.table1`.  Those would be the names that you use.

Comment: I was thinking that was the case. I am getting two errors when the query is run:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'